# WASM mimetype unsupported, pygbag error, used debug as well

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, pygbag

I've been trying for a couple of days now to convert my python program that uses the pygame module to a webpage using pygbag so I can integrate it in my website.

However, I keep getting this warning:

[WARNING: wasm mimetype unsupported on that system, trying to correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5d51O.png)

Below is the full code from my program:

```
import pygame, asyncio
from random import randint

class timePlaying(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        Timer = "0"
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.font = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", 12)
        self.textSurf = self.font.render(Timer, 1, "white")
        self.image = pygame.Surface((20, 10))
        self.image.fill((0,255,0))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=(20,10))
        W = self.textSurf.get_width()
        H = self.textSurf.get_height()
        self.image.blit(self.textSurf, [20/2 - W/2, 10/2 - H/2])

    def update(self, time):
        Timer = str(time)
        self.font = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", 12)
        self.textSurf = self.font.render(Timer, 1, "white")
        self.image = pygame.Surface((20, 10))
        self.image.fill((0,255,0))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=(10,5))
        W = self.textSurf.get_width()
        H = self.textSurf.get_height()
        self.image.blit(self.textSurf, [10/2 - W/2, 5/2 - H/2])
    
class Scoreboard1(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, size, color, width, height, locationY):
        CurrentScore1 = 0
        score = "Score: "+str(CurrentScore1)
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.font = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", size)
        self.textSurf = self.font.render(score, 1, color)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((width, height))
        self.image.fill((0,0,255))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=(400,locationY))
        W = self.textSurf.get_width()
        H = self.textSurf.get_height()
        self.image.blit(self.textSurf, [width/2 - W/2, height/2 - H/2])

    def update(self, CurrentScore1, size, color, width, height):
        CurrentScore1 += 1
        text1 = "Score: "+str(CurrentScore1)
        self.font = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", size)
        self.textSurf = self.font.render(text1, 1, color)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((width, height))
        self.image.fill((0,0,255))
        W = self.textSurf.get_width()
        H = self.textSurf.get_height()
        self.image.blit(self.textSurf, [width/2 - W/2, height/2 - H/2])
        return CurrentScore1

class Scoreboard2(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, size, color, width, height, locationY):
        CurrentScore2 = 0
        score = "Score: "+str(CurrentScore2)
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.font = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", size)
        self.textSurf = self.font.render(score, 1, color)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((width, height))
        self.image.fill((0,0,255))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=(400,locationY))
        W = self.textSurf.get_width()
        H = self.textSurf.get_height()
        self.image.blit(self.textSurf, [width/2 - W/2, height/2 - H/2])

    def update(self, CurrentScore2, size, color, width, height):
        CurrentScore2 += 1
        text1 = "Score: "+str(CurrentScore2)
        self.font = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", size)
        self.textSurf = self.font.render(text1, 1, color)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((width, height))
        self.image.fill((0,0,255))
        W = self.textSurf.get_width()
        H = self.textSurf.get_height()
        self.image.blit(self.textSurf, [width/2 - W/2, height/2 - H/2])
        return CurrentScore2

class Background(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image_file, location):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load(image_file)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.left, self.rect.top = location

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, location):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.surf = pygame.Surface((20, 50))
        self.rect = self.surf.get_rect()
        self.rect.left, self.rect.top = location

    def moveUp(self, pixels):
        self.rect.y -= pixels
        if self.rect.y < 0:
          self.rect.y = 0
          
    def moveDown(self, pixels):
        self.rect.y += pixels
        if self.rect.y > 500:
          self.rect.y = 500

class Goal(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image_file, location):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.surf = pygame.Surface((50, 61))
        self.surf.fill((255,255,255))
        self.image = pygame.image.load(image_file)
        self.rect = self.surf.get_rect(center=(location))

class StartOverlay(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image_file, location):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.surf = pygame.image.load(image_file)
        self.surf.fill((255, 255, 255, 200), None, pygame.BLEND_RGBA_MULT)
        self.rect = self.surf.get_rect(center=(location))

class Ball(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image_file):
        super(Ball, self).__init__()
        self.surf = pygame.Surface((20, 20))
        self.surf.fill((255,255,255))
        self.image = pygame.image.load(image_file)
        self.rect = self.surf.get_rect(center=(400,250,))
        self.velocity = [randint(4,8),randint(-8,8)]

    def update(self):
        self.rect.x += self.velocity[0]
        self.rect.y += self.velocity[1]

    def bounce(self):
        self.velocity[0] = -self.velocity[0]
        self.velocity[1] = randint(-8,8)

    def reset(self):
        self.surf = pygame.Surface((20, 20))
        self.surf.fill((255,255,255))
        self.rect = self.surf.get_rect(center=(400,250,))
        self.velocity = [randint(4,8),randint(-8,8)]
                                       
pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 500))
pygame.display.set_caption("Pong: Football edition")

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

scoreBoard1 = Scoreboard1(12,"white",100,50,25)
scoreBoard2 = Scoreboard2(12,"white",100,50,75)
timing = timePlaying()

startingOverlay = StartOverlay('start.png', [400,250])
player1 = Player(location =(50, 200))
player2 = Player(location =(720, 200))

all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
players = pygame.sprite.Group()
goals = pygame.sprite.Group()

BackGround = Background('pitch.jpg', [0,0])
ball = Ball('football.png')
goal1 = Goal('goal.jpg', [25,250])
goal2 = Goal('goal2.jpg', [775,250])

all_sprites.add(scoreBoard1)
all_sprites.add(scoreBoard2)
all_sprites.add(timing)
all_sprites.add(player1)
all_sprites.add(player2)
all_sprites.add(ball)
all_sprites.add(BackGround)
players.add(player1)
players.add(player2)
goals.add(goal1)
goals.add(goal2)

async def main():
    CurrentScore1 = 0
    CurrentScore2 = 0
    time = 0
    gameStarted = False
    run = True
    while run:
        clock.tick(50)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
            elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                pygame.time.set_timer(event, 1000)
                time += 1
                if not gameStarted:
                    gameStarted = True
                    startingOverlay.kill()

        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_w]:
            player1.moveUp(5)
        if keys[pygame.K_s]:
            player1.moveDown(5)
        if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
            player2.moveUp(5)
        if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            player2.moveDown(5)

        if ball.rect.x>=790:
            ball.velocity[0] = -ball.velocity[0]
        if ball.rect.x<=0:
            ball.velocity[0] = -ball.velocity[0]
        if ball.rect.y>490:
            ball.velocity[1] = -ball.velocity[1]
        if ball.rect.y<0:
            ball.velocity[1] = -ball.velocity[1]

        if pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(ball, players):
          ball.bounce()

        win.fill((0,0,0))
        win.blit(BackGround.image, BackGround.rect)
        if not gameStarted:
            win.blit(startingOverlay.surf, startingOverlay.rect)
        pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 255, 255), player1)
        pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 255, 255), player2)
        win.blit(ball.image, ball.rect)
        win.blit(goal1.image, goal1.rect)
        win.blit(goal2.image, goal2.rect)
        win.blit(scoreBoard1.image,scoreBoard1)
        win.blit(scoreBoard2.image,scoreBoard2)
        win.blit(timing.image, timing)
        timing.update(time)
        ball.update()
        pygame.display.update()


        if pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(ball, players):
            ball.update()

        goal_scored = pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(ball, goals)

        if goal_scored == goal2:
            ball.kill()
            CurrentScore1 = scoreBoard1.update(CurrentScore1,12,"white",100,50)
            ball.reset()

        if goal_scored == goal1:
            ball.kill()
            CurrentScore2 = scoreBoard2.update(CurrentScore2,12,"white",100,50)
            ball.reset()

        await asyncio.sleep(0)

asyncio.run(main())
```

Can anyone please help me sort out this error, I really want to integrate this pygame program as part of my website.

I tried to debug it by going to my link:

> http://localhost:8000/#debug

However, when I did that I received this error message from python:

[TypeError: 'pygame.event.Event' object cannot be interpreted as an integer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXO6x.png)

It looks like it's an error to do with loading the text fonts but I'm not sure how to fix that

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

That seems to be a [bug in the `platfrom_wasm` module](https://github.com/pygame-web/platform_wasm/blob/41bcbeb23503e910033b89579e0291fb4b250dee/platform_wasm/pygame/timer.py#L63) of the
[pygame-web project](https://github.com/pygame-web).

If we take a look at the code that patches the `pygame.time.set_timer` function:

```
def patch_set_timer(event: Union[int, pygame.event.Event], millis: int, loops: int = 0):
    """Patches the pygame.time.set_timer function to use gthreads"""

    dlay = float(millis) / 1000
    cevent = pygame.event.Event(event)
    event_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    ...
```

We see the line `cevent = pygame.event.Event(event)`. The `pygame.event.Event` constructor expects an `int` value, but in your case `event` is already an `pygame.event.Event`.

Even the type hint (`Union[int, pygame.event.Event]`) makes it clear that passing an `pygame.event.Event` should work.

I don't know what you're trying to do with the timed event anyway, so I suggest you simply remove the line (`pygame.time.set_timer(event, 1000)`) for the time being.

Comment: I changed the time thing but then there was an error with the fonts which I fixed and now it (finally) works. With that line I was setting a timer that counts up every 1 second to show time playing.